# In the Gospels, How Should the Hours of the Day be Understood?

Tags: contradiction, gospels, chronology

Per [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/at-what-time-of-day-was-jesus-crucified), there was a comment suggesting that the 6th hour may actually be the 3rd hour - or even the noon hour.

Being unfamiliar with this, how is the 6th hour possibly the same as the 3rd hour?

**Mark 15:25, 18 KJV**

> And it was the **third hour**, and they crucified him.

and

> And began to salute him, Hail, King of the Jews!

**John 19:14-16 KJV**

> And it was the preparation of the passover, and about the **sixth hour**: and he saith unto the Jews, Behold your King!
>   But they cried out, Away with him, away with him, crucify him. Pilate saith unto them, Shall I crucify your King? The chief priests answered, We have no king but Caesar.
>   Then delivered he him therefore unto them to be crucified. And they took Jesus, and led him away.

Comment: Perhaps the question heading could be corrected for 'Judaism' to help people find this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## About Time

### Does not need to be "the same" time, and is not the same time

Notice that the Mk 15:25 (3rd hour) is stated as "when they crucified him." In the Jn 19:14 passage (6th hour) the reference is to when Pilate sat in his place of judgement for the final condemnation of Christ to the cross.

### There are time differences

The easy way to state it is that there are at least two main time reckoning systems that are being referenced. Commentators vary in that some will call one set the "Jewish" reckoning, and the other the "Roman," and others will refer to them in the opposite fashion. For purposes here, all that matters is the fact that the two differing systems existed. I will also refer to one set as "Jewish" and the other "Roman" based off what the majority of commentators I have looked at tend to equate the periods with, and that [this Jewish reference supports](http://torahcalendar.com/HOUR.asp).

So in parallel with our modern clock times, we have the following (note that this is an approximation for the Jewish reckoning especially, as they actually divided the daylight hours into 12 [cf. Jn 11:9], which may be more/less than a true hour depending upon time of year, etc.):

```
12 mid  - Roman start of day | Jewish 6th hour night
3:00am  - Roman 3rd hour     | Jewish 9th hour of night
6:00am  - Roman 6th hour     | Jewish start of day (sunrise)
9:00am  - Roman 9th hour     | Jewish 3rd hour day
12 noon - Roman 12th hour    | Jewish 6th hour day
3:00pm  - Roman 3rd hour     | Jewish 9th hour day 
6:00pm  - Roman 6th hour     | Jewish 12th hour (sunset)
9:00pm  - Roman 9th hour     | Jewish 3rd hour of night
```

It is well attested that [Roman's reckoned the day from midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_timekeeping_system#Beginning_of_the_Roman_day).
What is debated is whether they reckoned the *hours of the day* from that point or not.<sup>1</sup> There seems to be evidence that both forms of reckoning were used, which is really enough to open the possibility that the two schedules resolve the issues between the gospels.

## About the Situation Eliciting this Question

### A Possible Time Frame Given the Evidence (times are approximate)

**5:00-5:30am** Early in the morning (i.e. the [dawn's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn) morning [twilight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight); Mt 27:1; Mk 15:1; Lk 22:66),<sup>2</sup> the Sanhedrin had already gathered for the "quick" trial of Christ at this time, and then sent him to Pilate while it was still "early" (Jn 18:28).

**5:30am-6:30am** Examination of Pilate, then Herod, and Pilate's delivering to scourge Jesus, and his final judgment to crucify him (Herod must have been nearby, his palace was not far from where the action was, but he may not have even been there, but rather nearby in the judgment area itself).

[image]

<sub>Map from http://www.ccel.org/bible/phillips/CP051GOSPELMAPS.htm</sub>

Note that John only says "about the sixth hour" which leaves a fair bit of play for actual time (perhaps even up to 7:00am). This would be Roman reckoning if the time frames are going to fit,<sup>3</sup> which also fits the audience John would have been writing to, being after the destruction of Jerusalem in A.D. 70.

**9:00am** About this time, the 3rd hour by Jewish reckoning, that Jesus is actually nailed to the cross (Mk 15:25), the final mocking of the soldiers and march to Golgotha being the span of time between.

**12:00 noon - 3:00pm** From the 6th to 9th hour (Jewish reckoning), darkness comes "over all the land" (Mt 27:45; Mk 15:33; Lk 23:44). At the end of this time is when Christ actually dies (MT 27:50; Mk 15:37; Lk 23:46; Jn 19:30).

### No Day Discrepancy

Some have noted that there is not only a supposed time discrepancy, but also a whole day discrepancy. Jn 19:14 states "it was **the Preparation Day of the Passover**" that Christ is before Pilate and dies later that day. This is deemed to be in conflict with the synoptic gospels that note the first day of the feast of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover is to be killed (i.e. the day that Jews are preparing to observe the Passover), was the day before the evening meal with the disciples in the upper room, and so they had prepared the passover during that day (Mt 26:17, Mk 14:12, Lk 22:7). Thus the supposed day discrepancy.

However, the Synoptic Gospels themselves speak of another preparation day, which does align with the day Christ is crucified. Matthew 27:62-64 (NKJV for all quotes):

> On the next day, **which followed the Day of Preparation**, the chief
>   priests and Pharisees gathered together to Pilate, saying, “Sir, we
>   remember, while He was still alive, how that deceiver said, ‘After
>   three days I will rise.’ Therefore command that the tomb be made
>   secure until the third day, lest His disciples come by night and steal
>   Him away, and say to the people, ‘He has risen from the dead.’ So the
>   last deception will be worse than the first.

Recall that Joseph had rapidly buried Jesus right at the end of the day of crucifixion, during the evening twilight hours (Mt 27:57) before the setting of the sun. At sunset would have been the start of the Passover itself, and it is that "next day" when the chief priests make the request above. That is, they requested this of Pilate after sunset, right after Christ was buried in the tomb by Joseph.

Mark 15:42 states:

> Now when evening had come, because **it was the Preparation Day**, that
>   is, the day before the Sabbath, Joseph of Arimathea, a prominent council member, who was himself waiting for the kingdom of God, coming and taking courage, went in to Pilate and asked for the body of Jesus.

This puts Jesus being crucified on a day of preparation. As also Luke 23:50-54, which states:

> Now behold, there was a man named Joseph, a council member, a good
>   and just man. He had not consented to their decision and deed. He
>   was from Arimathea, a city of the Jews, who himself was also waiting
>   for the kingdom of God. This man went to Pilate and asked for the
>   body of Jesus. Then he took it down, wrapped it in linen, and laid
>   it in a tomb that was hewn out of the rock, where no one had ever lain
>   before. **That day was the Preparation**, and the Sabbath drew near.

So John's statement "it was the Preparation Day of the Passover" (Jn 19:14) is *not* referring to the preparation day *for* the Passover, but a special instance of a preparation day for the Sabbath that was following the day of the Passover, and thus the preparation *on* the Passover day for the next day's Sabbath. That the priests had not yet eaten the passover the morning Christ was crucified (Jn 18:28) was because they had been busy about handling the matter of capturing and condemning Christ that night, before the first *day* (daylight hours) of the feast. They still wanted to partake, and thus did not enter the Gentile domain of Pilate in order to not be defiled before they could eat (which was all very hypocritical of them).

**So all four gospel accounts have it on a day of preparation for the Sabbath day that was following the Passover day that Christ was crucified.**

---

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> D. R. W. Wood and I. Howard Marshall in *New Bible Dictionary* (Leicester, England; Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press, 1996) argue Roman and Jewish accounting of hours in a day matched. For one who considers the time schedule reversed between Jewish/Roman reckoning, see Norman L. Geisler, "'Avoid… Contradictions' (1 Timothy 6:20): A Reply To John Dahms," *Journal of the Evangelical Theological Society* 22 (1979), 64 n.17, where he refers to the works of the 1st century Jew Flavius Josephus' biographical work "The Life of Falvius Josephus." However, in my looking up Geisler's reference, it appeared to me that the 6th hour by Josephus' reckoning was in accord with the Jewish timekeeping I've given above.

<sup>2</sup> Using information from the twilight page, a "rough" calculation for the Jerusalem area would put the twilight time before sunrise at 28-39 minutes.

<sup>3</sup> I do not hold to a hermeneutic that allows for John to change the time/day for "theological purposes." I hold that the Bible is God's word, absolute truth, and inerrant in what was originally recorded and within what has been preserved for us from that original in the copies (note that this does not mean each copy is inerrant, only those that are *truly* copies that match the original reading, which we have within the extant manuscript copies we possess today).

Comment: Lots of work here! OP's question was about time rather than date, but since you address the latter, it would be worth comparing notes with H.K. Bond, "[Dating the Death of Jesus: Memory and the Religious Imagination](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0028688513000131)", *New Testament Studies* 59.4 (2013): 461-75.

Comment: @Davïd: Thanks, I'll take a look. Yes, I addressed the date because both another answer here as well as the original question on C.SE that elicited this question had answers following a "theological" change by John argument, which I felt could not go unanswered (since I do not believe that is true).

Comment: @ScottS -  ***A.)** Actually - The Wiki article you cite states : *"The Roman civil and religious day began at midnight from a very early time.[8] Modern opinions of this, by ones such as Unger (1892) and Ramsay (1896) maintain that **the hours of the day and the night were always counted from dusk, or dawn**, hence that the "sixth hour" represented midnight or midday respectively."*  **B.)** Since the references you cite affirm this - I am not sure what the "debate" is - and the burden of proof remains, to show otherwise.

Comment: @elikakohen: The debate is noted in the very next sentence from what you quoted: "Yet following classic Roman thinking, Jack Finegan (1964) argues that the 'sixth hour' can be counted from midnight." So there is a debate.

Comment: @ScottS - **A.)** *"Jack Finegan ... argues that the "sixth hour" can be counted from midnight.  He maintained this position **despite not having any evidence at all**. ... he referenced ... Jesus was at Pilate (sixth hour)"*;  **B.)** It seems more valid to note that this ***opinion*** is based on presupposing the authority of Christian texts, to disprove overwhelming historical evidence.  **C.)** In Hermeneutics, this is "begging the question" - and unreliable. **D.)** I understand this doctrine; but ***it is exactly that basis of Finegan's opinion that is being examined in this question.***

Answer (score 2):

Although the Jews began their days at dusk and Romans began their days at midnight, that is not how either civilisation measured the passage of time. Simply speaking, the mechanical clock had not yet been invented. E. G. Richards describes in *Mapping Time* how shadow clocks were used to divide the hours of daylight up into exactly 12 hours of variable length according to the season. Measuring time accurately at night was also possible, based on the stars, but difficult and of no interest to most people. It was not until the invention of mechanical clocks that we changed over to a variable number of hours of daylight, each of fixed length throughout the year.

Using the universal shadow clock, the third hour was the third of daylight and the sixth hour was precisely noon. Thus, they were never the same hour. The explanation is that we find not one but two differences between Mark (and the other synoptic gospels) and John, not only in the time at which Jesus was crucified, either the third hour (9 o'clock) or the sixth hour 12 o'clock), but even the day. Mark says that the Last Supper, on the evening before the crucifixion, was also the Passover feast. John 19:14 tells us that the crucifixion took place on the day of ***preparation*** for the Passover. Ian Wilson says in *Jesus: The Evidence* it is possible that John, in his desire to represent Jesus as the new “paschal lamb”, distorted history to have the crucifixion occur when lambs would have been slaughtered in the Temple in preparation for the Passover

For theological reasons, the author of John has changed both the date and time of the crucifixion, to coincide with the time that Jews killed the sacrificial lamb for the Passover. In John's Gospel, Jesus is, by analogy, the lamb of God.

Comment: John didn't just change the *date* of the crucifixion; he also changed other details to be consistent with a 14 Nisan date.  For example, in *John*, when the other apostles see Judas' bag of silver, they assume he's using it to buy food for the Passover feast.  But in the synoptics, they *just ate* the Passover feast.  (Pointed out by [Rabbi Tovia Singer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0bLpdP1x8I).)

Answer (score 2):

They are the same hours that have been preserved within the [Orthodox Christian Daily Cycle of Prayers](https://orthodoxwiki.org/Hours)

> - **First Hour** corresponds to daybreak (6:00 a.m.).
> - **Third Hour** corresponds to mid-morning (9:00 a.m.)
> - **Sixth Hour** corresponds to mid-day (12:00 noon)
> - **Ninth Hour** corresponds to mid-afternoon (3:00 p.m.)

Regarding the discrepancy between John's and Mark's account of the hour at which Jesus was crucified, there are three explanations that I am aware of:

First, some manuscripts (including the Codex Sinaiticus, which is the most ancient on hand following the Vaticanus) actually do indicate "the third hour" instead of "the sixth hour", though Metzger discounts this as "an obvious attempt to harmonize the chronology" (*A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament*, 2nd ed.).

Second, certain Church Fathers (e.g. Eusebius and Jerome) ascribe the discrepancy due to a transcription error, wherein a copiest confused the Greek symbol used for 3 - the letter Γ' (*gamma*) - with a special character called the *episemon* - denoted by ϝ - used to represent the number 6.  Theophylact of Ohrid, writing in the 11th century, explains how this might have occurred:

> The letter gamma represents the ordinal number 3 and is used to
>   indicate the third hour.  A special character called the *episemon* or
>   "symbol" represents the number 6 and is used to indicate the sixth
>   hour.  It is possible that a scribe inadvertantly altered the gamma,
>   rounding and lengthening the upright line, so that it resembled the
>   episemon.  Thus John in all likelihood wrote *the third hour*, and
>   not, *the sixth hour*, as we now read in the text.  The other three
>   evangelists - Matthew, Mark, and Luke - agree that form the sixth hour
>   there was darkness over all the land until the ninth hour [Mt 27:45;
>   Mk 15:25,33; Lk 23:44].  This indicates that the Lord was crucified
>   before it became dark at the sixth hour; that is, at the third hour,
>   as Mark states [15:23] and the other two imply.
>
> [*Explanation of the Gospel According to Saint John*](http://www.chrysostompress.org/catalog_explanation_4s.html) (tr.
>   Chrysostom Press: 2007), p.282

A third explanation, also posited by Theophylact, is that the third hour was the hour at which the crucifixion order was issued by Pilate, but that the actual crucifixion might not have actually occurred until three hours later.  Theophylact points out that a number of events took place between the hour of judgment and the time of crucifixion:

> Consider how many events took place from the time when Pilate decided
>   to crucify the Lord to the time when He was nailed to the cross. 
>   Pilate released Barabbas (this constituted the Lord's condemnation),
>   had Jesus scourged, and handed Him over to be crucified.  The soldiers
>   spent a long time taunting Christ with their elaborate burlesque. 
>   Pilate brought jesus out and spoke with the Jews, after which he took
>   Him back inside to judge Him.  Then he went out again and tried to
>   reason with the Jews.  So it was at the sixth hour, mentioned by John,
>   that Pilate at last gave up on winning over the Jews, stopped
>   questioning Jesus, and rendered his final decision by handing Him over
>   to them.

Comment: Nice addition, thanks.  How do you think this rationalizes the differences between Mark and John?

Comment: It doesn't really, but I added some additional information I found that might address that question.

Comment: 9th=3pm, 6th=noon, 3rd=9am: these all make sense.  But 1st=6am doesn't. When was the 2nd hour, at 7:30am?

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that with the Greek word **ὡς (hōs)** which means “about/approximately” being used in John 19:14 entails John’s point that it was roughly coming on the sixth hour of the day (12:00 noon) by the time Christ was being crucified.

The texts at hand:

> “Therefore when Pilate heard these words, he brought Jesus out, and
> sat down on the judgment seat at a place called The Pavement, but in
> Hebrew, Gabbatha.
>
> **Now it was the day of preparation for the Passover; it was about the
> sixth hour.**
>
> And he *said to the Jews, “Behold, you’re King!” So they cried out,
> “Away with Him, away with Him, crucify Him!” Pilate *said to them,
> “Shall I crucify your King?” The chief priests answered, “We have no
> king but Caesar.”” ‭‭John‬ ‭19‬:‭13‬-‭15‬ ‭NASB1995

‬‬cf.

> “**It was the third hour when they crucified Him**.
>
> save Yourself, and come down from the cross!” ‭‭Mark‬ ‭15‬:‭25‬, ‭30‬
> ‭NASB1995

‬‬Verse 30 shows that by 9:00 A.M. Jesus was up on the cross, if He was being taunted to come down from the cross then He was fully installed onto it.

The chronology may go as follows:

1.) Jesus was crucified at the 9:00A.M. Hour

2.) Jesus was crucified at **about** ”ὡς (hōs)” the sixth hour.

It would appear likely that John was giving a rough estimate and since the sun at 9:00A.M. can be judged as roughly noon.  Time keeping was more difficult in antiquity and not as precise as today’s clocks.

This should not be a chronological problem and it doesn’t hinder divine inspiration of the gospels either.

Wether or not a sundial was used in the time measurements for Christ’s crucifixion is not listed in the gospel accounts.

**ὡς** Definition:

[https://www.billmounce.com/greekvocabulary/ὡς](https://www.billmounce.com/greekvocabulary/%E1%BD%A1%CF%82)

Answer (score 0):

There were considered to be 12 hours in the "day" (which is equivalent to "daylight") and an additional 12 hours for the night.  Each of these is begun and ended at approximately sunrise or sunset.

In those days, remember, they did not have clocks such as we have today.  Their "clock" was a sun dial, and measured by the shadow of the sun.

The "third hour" corresponds to mid-morning, about 9:00 a.m.  Again, this is not measured based on a super-precise atomic clock such as sets our standards today.  It was measured by the light of the sun.

The "sixth hour" corresponds to mid-day, about noon.

The "ninth hour" corresponds to about mid-afternoon, or 3:00 p.m.

Those are the times established for the "day."  If the hour given is the "sixth hour" but the context shows it to have occurred during the night, then the hour was, of course, midnight, not noon.

> Jesus answered, Are there not twelve hours in the day? If any man walk
> in the day, he stumbleth not, because he seeth the light of this
> world. (John 11:9, KJV)

The context of Jesus' statement clearly indicates he was speaking of the daytime, not nighttime.  In total, just as we have today, there were 24 hours.  And, then just as today, the hours of the night were called by the same terms as those of the day, e.g. "3 o'clock" ("ninth hour") could be a time in the afternoon or the pre-dawn night.

The main distinction is that, in place of the sun's *zenith,* they counted the hours by its passing of the *horizon.*

Answer (score 0):

As I’ve been blessed by Messiah יהושע (Yahushua), whom I serve:

And recently corrected by @raygrant, which is much appreciated!

When reading the Bible, Tanakh (Hebrew Scriptures / Old Testament) or Brit Chadashah (New Testament), always refer to the Hebrew Calendar for dates, and use the relative hour, also known as the Halachic hour, for times.  This is important to maintain prophetic understanding.

In the Bible, by changing any numerical value, including a date, time, or even the way a number is written in the original Hebrew, this will cause a loss of Prophetic Meaning.

Found In Yuhanan (John) 11:9-10, we see that the  Messiah יהושע said:

“Are there not twelve hours in the day? If anyone walks during the day, he does not stumble, because he sees the light of this world.  But if anyone walks during the night, he stumbles, because the light is not in him.” (NASB)

Messiah יהושע is the Light, and the twelve hours in a day reference here refers to the relative hour that was maintained at this time, and still is maintained in Judaism when considering scripture and prophecy.

It is said that Both Jews, and Romans used the relative hour during the recording of the Gospel, and certain technologies used to tell time, like sundials, would adjust in one way or another to maintain the relative hour.

The relative hour is found by taking the amount of daylight at sunrise until sunset, and dividing it by 12.  Thus you have twelve equal hours in every day.

It is said that during this time, every sundial that held the Halachic hour maintained that the First Hour was always at sunrise, Noon was always on the 7th hour, and the 12th hour was always at sunset.

Check the quick link below for a jstor snippet of this information:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/41134104

Consider this when reading the set hours that Yuhanan speaks of.

In understanding this, as I have been led by Messiah יהושע to believe, the Messiah released His Spirit on the Seventh hour during the brightest time of day, Noon.

I say this because the Messiah יהושע had perfectly completed the Father’s will, and He is the Light.  After noon, the brightest time of day, the Light begins to dim, until it is dark again.  But The Darkness has not overcome the Light, and in the end, the Light will return, and there will be no darkness.

Our Heavenly Father is the Great Light, and His Messiah, יהושע, is the Lamp.

The Gospel account of Yuhanan is the only truly inspired gospel account, and has minimal tampering.  Yuhanan says nothing about a third and ninth hour when referring to the Messiahs crucifixion.

I believe that the synoptic gospels (Matthew, Mark, and Luke) are Apocryphal.  The book of acts is written by Luke, it too is Apocryphal.  The Body of Messiah will make new acts, and the Father will perform great signs, miracles, and wonders through those who proclaim His One Lamb, Messiah יהושע, as Master.

According to The Gospel account of Yuhanan, Chapter 19:

Already been beaten terribly, Messiah יהושע was then judged by Pontius Pilate and handed to the soldiers to be crucified near the sixth hour.  This was one relative hour before the brightest time of day.

Messiah יהושע then carried His cross 600 Meters to Golbotha where He was then crucified with one on His left, another on His right.

Yuhanan does not record that the Messiah suffered for an extended amount of time after being crucified.

What He says is, knowing that all was completed, the Messiah said, “I thirst”, He was then given sour vinegar to drink, a reference to the law of the jealous husband and adulterous woman.  יהושע then said, “It is Finished”, He then bowed His head, and released His Spirit.

Consider how Mosheh (Moses) died on Mount Nebo.  What about his brother Aharon (Aaron).  This was Instantaneous.

Again, I believe the Messiah released His Spirit on the seventh hour, during the brightest time of day, Noon.

Hopefully this helps give understanding as to how time worked back then.  And perhaps you will consider the alternative belief for the timing of our Heavenly Father’s one sacrifice for all sin.  The Spotless Lamb of God Most High, Messiah יהושע, Son of David.

God Bless.

And again, thanks for pointing out my error @raygrant

This turned out to be a great blessing!

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, it should have been better to deal with the use of "clocks" in the first century by the Romans, and by the Jews. That is, when did the first hour begin, midnight (like modernity) or in the morning (six o'clock out time)?  Your answer deal with exhortations which deviate from the intent of the question. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

Answer (score 0):

A Day STARTS biblically at SUNSET.  We know that CONCLUSIVELY from Genesis  There was an EVENING and morning, the first day.  That concept is reinforced by the fact that Shabbot STARTS at SUNSET.